# Excel VBA to auto-fill website checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, checkbox, autocomplete

My coding knowledge is quite limited, but I need some help from you guys.

The data in an excel table with 3 columns and 3 rows should be automatically marked into the 3x3 checkboxes on a web page. Chrome will be used.

I try to explain in the attached picture.

[image]

Can you help me with the vba code? Just filling in the boxes will suffice. There will be no click to save.

Thank you very much, best regards.

I tried to do it with Selenium but failed, I need working codes.

Comment: You need to share your code for your try/tries, and point to where you get stuck, so we can help you in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.